# Set default include paths in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

Every time I start a new project, then the same *ancient* include paths are in there. I can't fint any thing about, how to set default [include paths in the phpstorm documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-include-paths.html).

How do I change these for all new projects?

[image: default include paths in phpstorm]

---

### Way to recreate

If I just create an empty folder and Click 'Open' and choose that folder. Then if I after that go to the PHP-settings as shown above, then those Include Paths are there.

Comment: Side question: what do you mean "ancient"? Paths that belong to some OLD/no-longer-in-use project ... or are you reffering to "include paths" words (as in "nobody uses thatnow")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I change these for all new projects?

You must have set those 2 entries previously in the wrong place.

You need to change defaults for new projects (this will affect all future new projects created on this computer):

```
File | New Projects Settings | Settings for New Projects...
```

[image]

P.S. You seems to be on Mac, where you access settings for the current project/IDE settings via "PhpStorm | Preferences" while on Linux & Windows it's "File | Settings". Some time ago this "wrong" option was called "Default Settings" which was confusing for some (especially Mac) users that were editing the wrong settings.